# Weight & Biases Detectron2 Google Colab - wandb: ERROR Unable to log event [Errno 95] Operation not supported

Tags: python, pytorch, google-colaboratory

I am training a Faster-RCNN model by Detectron2 in Google Colab. I would like to track my experiments with Weights and Biases (WandB).

My dataset is uploaded to Google Drive and mounted to the session via:

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/gdrive')
```

Following the suggestion from https://github.com/facebookresearch/detectron2/issues/774
I am trying to link WandB via Tensorboard with:

```
import wandb
wandb.init(sync_tensorboard=True)
```

Once the training starts I get the following error repeatedly:

```
wandb: ERROR Unable to log event [Errno 95] Operation not supported: '/content/gdrive/My Drive/Data/output/events.out.tfevents.1598810231.3dc4616192b5.103.0' -> '/content/gdrive/My Drive/Data/wandb/run-20200830_175618-3fp3tyhs/events.out.tfevents.1598810231.3dc4616192b5.103.0'
```

In this case, in my WandB account, I can see that there is an active experiment running but there are no logs of losses, learning rate, etc., only hardware info like the specs of the GPU show up.

Interestingly, when I add the linking between Tensorboard and WandB in the Demo Colab Notebook of Detectron2 (https://colab.research.google.com/drive/16jcaJoc6bCFAQ96jDe2HwtXj7BMD_-m5), it works perfectly: the logging of losses, learning rate, etc shows up in my WandB account.

Can I get some tips regarding what is going wrong in my case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After one week the problem disappeared. I assume that someone must have fixed the bug that caused this issue. I can now use:

```
import wandb
wandb.init(sync_tensorboard=True)
```

and all the training metrics are synchronized to WandB without any problems.